# sql between for DAYSOFWEEK

Tags: sql, range, between, dayofweek

I have a generalized search where I'm looking up average prices for the various days of the week.  The problem is I'm not sure how to ask for an odd range.  1-7 works fine, (monday-sunday), but if the user passes a sunday to a tuesday... ie 7-2 it doesn't work.

1-7 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
7-2 (7,1,2)

etc.

How else can I pass a range that is more intelligent or something besides BETWEEN?

```
SELECT item_id, DAYOFWEEK(bookdate) as date, bookdate, AVG(price) AS price 
FROM `availables` WHERE (item_id = 16 and DAYOFWEEK(bookdate) BETWEEN 2 AND 7) 
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(bookdate)
```

Comment: i would use the dates that exist, but i'm working with scraped data and the dates might not exist so it uses past dates on non specific days of the week for avg prices. IE prices tend to be higher on fridays and saturdays, but lower on sundays and mondays., etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the IN syntax:

```
SELECT item_id, DAYOFWEEK(bookdate) as date, bookdate, AVG(price) AS price 
FROM `availables` WHERE (item_id = 16 and DAYOFWEEK(bookdate) IN (7,1,2)) 
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(bookdate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it with an 'in' clause, like this: dayofweek(bookdate) in (1,2,7)

This also allows the flexibility of non-continuous dates (select records for Monday and Friday only, for example)